# How to define action='store_true' in absl

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, absl-py

I am migrating code from argparse to absl (The python version is 3.6). The code using argparse has the following

```
  parser.add_argument('--flip_left_right', default=False,
  help="flip", action='store_true')
```

Using absl, I can define the flag with the following code

```
flags.DEFINE_bool("flip_left_right", False, "flip")
```

But I cannot define "action" in absl (which will report error "unexpected keyword argument 'action'" if I do so). How can I define the action='store_true' in absl? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this link:- https://medium.com/python4you/consider-absl-python-library-to-work-with-flags-a69b536e6b61

Comment: The link is helpful, thank you. In absl, action='store_true' is not necessary.